# How can i check if a Tweeter user can get direct messages using tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, message, tweepy, dm

Some of the Tweeter users can get direct messages and some cannot.
I want a bot that finds the users that can get DM **without sending** them.
Is that an option?

these are the user's arguments:

blocked_by
blocking
contributors_enabled
created_at  datetime.datetime(2009, 7, 27, 10, 25, 17)
default_profile
default_profile_image
description
entities
favourites_count
follow_request_sent
followers_count
following
friends_count
geo_enabled
has_extended_profile
id
id_str
is_translation_enabled
is_translator
lang
listed_count
location
muting
name
notifications
profile_background_color
profile_background_image_url
profile_background_image_url_https
profile_background_tile
profile_banner_url
profile_image_url
profile_image_url_https
profile_link_color
profile_sidebar_border_color
profile_sidebar_fill_color
profile_text_color
profile_use_background_image
protected
screen_name
status
statuses_count
time_zone
translator_
url
utc_offset
verified
withheld_in_countries

Answer (score 0):

There's no such feature available in v2 yet. But in v1.1, it’s available under `GET friendships/show`. The response includes parameter `can_dm` (i.e. if you can DM the other user).

Reference: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-friendships-show

Comment: how can i work with v1.1?
it seems like im stuck with the v2...

thank you anyway!